# Flutter - Endless notification on a single pusher beams event

Tags: flutter, dart, pusher, flutter-local-notification

**Describe the bug**

I am using pusher beams to fire event from server and I use flutter local notification to show the notification when the event is received by app.

**Sample code to reproduce the problem**

I have called `initPusherBeams()` in my init state (please read to the end I am quite sure this issues is with flutter local notifications)

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _setAuthData().then((_) {
      if (_user?.id != null) initPusherBeams();
    });

    // notification related
    _notiInit();
    _requestPermissions();
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject();
    _configureSelectNotificationSubject();

    // ask for app rating
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _ratingDialog());
  }
```

and then, in`initPusherBeams` function, I have

```dart
  initPusherBeams() async {
    // Let's see our current interests
    await PusherBeams.instance.setDeviceInterests([
      // 'App.Models.User.${_user!.id}',
      'debug-new'
    ]);

    // This is not intented to use in web
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      await PusherBeams.instance.onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(_onMessageReceivedInTheForeground);
    }
  }

  void _onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(Map<Object?, Object?> data) {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel',
      'My App Name',
      channelDescription: 'New user registered',
      playSound: false,
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
    );

    const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(presentSound: false);

    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    log(json.encode(data));

    // flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    //   0,
    //   'New user registered',
    //   data['body'].toString(),
    //   platformChannelSpecifics,
    //   payload: data['title'].toString(),
    // );
  }
```

If I comment out `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show`, the event fire only once as you can see in below screenshot.

[image: Screenshot without error]

but if I uncomment showing notification part which is the following code

```dart
 flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'New user registered',
      data['body'].toString(),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: data['title'].toString(),
    );
```

The event fire endlessly (like in the screenshot below) and the notification keep appearing for each event continuously.

[image: Screenshot with error]

How come showing notification became some kind of loop and how should I fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up showing the notification with SnackBar while the app is in foreground. While the apps is in background, the pusher beams package handle the notification and send it to notification center. Here's my code

````dart
  initPusherBeams() async {
    // Let's see our current interests
    await PusherBeams.instance.setDeviceInterests([
      'App.Models.User.${_user!.id}',
      'debug-new'
    ]);

    // This is not intented to use in web
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      await PusherBeams.instance.onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(_onMessageReceivedInTheForeground);
    }
  }

  void _onMessageReceivedInTheForeground(Map<Object?, Object?> data) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(correctFont(data['body'] as String)),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
        backgroundColor: brandBrown,
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Comment: In my case when the app is in the background pusher beam is not showing a heads-up notification. do you face this error?

Comment: @KashifAliBhatti if you are using flutter try learning this example app to avoid unnecessary errors. 

https://github.com/pusher/push-notifications-flutter/tree/master/packages/pusher_beams/example

Comment: How do you handle background notifications using pusher beams? Pusher beams does not have a background notification handler like `PusherBeams.instance.onMessageReceivedInTheForeground`.

Comment: @AkshayDoshi If you received a message in foreground, it means that user is currently using your app. So, you can just display the message using `AlertDialog` or `Snackbar` depending on your preference. (Or increase the count where you are displaying the in-app notification like a bell icon or similar)

You only need push notification when user is not using your app.